# Query to calculate age of a member based on the Date of birth and Current date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to calculate the age of a member based on the Date of birth and Current date, and then classify that age into categories like Under 30, 31-40,41-50,51-60 and Above 60.
Can some one help me with this query?

Comment: If you are storing the result when you categorize the person you are really just saying how old they were at the time they were *added to the database*.  One year from now, a large percentage of that data will be invalid.

Comment: No calculated fields in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which DBMS you are using but this should get you started. (Below code is for MSSQL)

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Username varchar(64), BirthDate  Datetime)


INSERT INTO @Table
    VALUES ('User1', '2001-Jan-01')
INSERT INTO @Table
    VALUES ('User2', '1965-Jan-01')
INSERT INTO @Table
    VALUES ('User3', '1964-Jan-01')
INSERT INTO @Table
    VALUES ('User4', '1995-Jan-01')
INSERT INTO @Table
    VALUES ('User5', '1970-Jan-01')
INSERT INTO @Table
    VALUES ('User6', '1955-Jan-01')
INSERT INTO @Table
    VALUES ('User7', '1989-Jan-01')
INSERT INTO @Table
    VALUES ('User8', '1976-Jan-01')


;
WITH AgeData as
(
SELECT
    Username,
    Birthdate,
    DATEDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, GETDATE()) AS AGE
FROM @Table)
SELECT
    Username,
    Birthdate,
    Age,
    CASE
        WHEN AGE < 30 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'Under 30',
    CASE
        WHEN AGE BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS '31 - 40',
    CASE
        WHEN AGE BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS '41 - 50',
    CASE
        WHEN AGE > 50 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'Over 50'
FROM AgeData
```

Comment: When specifying hard-coded dates like that, you should use the ISO8601 or ODBC canonical format to ensure SQL Server doesn't inadvertently misread your dates.  For instance, `1976-Jan-01` should actually be `1976-01-01T00:00:00` or at least `1976-01-01 00:00:00`.